# dhcp without dns: ping `hostname` not working. Auto add hostname to /etc/hosts?

Tags: networking, rhel, init-script, hook

On RHEL 6.5 how to make my own hostname locally resolvable, if my ip address is dynamic and not registered in DNS?

I know, it's possible to add dhcp hook scripts. Is there a similar way to hook the network initscript, so this works with static config too?

Comment: Do you need to use your network IP? What about the loopback address (127.0.0.1)?

Answer (score 1):

There's a standard custom script `/sbin/ifup-local`. It is called for each adapter. My script obtains the ip and hostnames and adds them to `/etc/hosts`

```
#!/bin/bash
# /sbin/ifup-local
set -e

fn_get_ip() {
ip addr show dev "$1" | sed "s,.* inet \([^/]*\)/.*,\1,;t;d"
}

fn_aaa() {
ip=`fn_get_ip "$1"`
hostnames=`hostname | sed "s,\([^.]*\)\..*,\1 &,"`

hint='# added by ifup-local'
sed -i "/$hint/d" /etc/hosts
echo "$ip $hostnames $hint" >>/etc/hosts
}

case $1 in
eth*)
fn_aaa "$1"
;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **avahi** daemon to bind your IP address to some resolvable host name (e.g. linux.local) each time when your IP is changed by DHCP.